# Can't suppress passphrase prompt automating GPG decryption

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Windows 7, GnuPG 2.1.19

I'm having a hell of time trying to automate decryption of files using GPG. I've tried all of the variations that I can find to pass the passphrase to the command line, but all continue to prompt me via the pop-up box. And, yes, I understand the security implications of including the passphrase in the command line, passphrase file, batch file, etc. Apparently, most people can get this to work:

> echo mypassphrase| gpg --batch --output test.csv --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt test.csv.pgp

I've tried using the --passphrase-file  switch. I've tried using --passphrase mypassphrase. I've tried various spacing and quoting variations. I'm pulling my hair out here. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: As a clarification, it appears that the command above will work sometimes, and only after I've entered the passphrase manually once (it'll sometimes work on subsequent runs of a PowerShell program in which I'm running it.)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem on my own. I found that in version 2.1x of GnuPG, you have to add the "--pinentry-mode loopback" option and value.

Comment: But do we need to set up anything?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean do we need to update or set up the gpg agent config to make the pinentry-mode-loopback enabled or is that the default option? The issue is I cannot locate my gpg agent config file and so dont understand where to set this up.

Comment: can you please share the code that you used for the command for decryption using the --pintentry-mode? Thank you

Comment: I'm using the following command in a batch file, where parameter 1 (%1) is the decrypted filename and parameter 2 (%2) is the encrypted filename:
echo <passphrase> | "C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" --batch  --output %1  --passphrase-fd 0 --pinentry-mode loopback --decrypt %2

Comment: Also, I didn't explicitly configure GPG to enable pinentry mode. it appears that it's required in version 2.1x by default if you want to suppress the passphrase prompt.